# How to delete the last xml node and its child with boost lib?

Tags: xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I want to remove a node from an XML file.

XML string looks like:

```
<BookData>
   <Book><Author>A1<Author><Name>B1</Name><Price>C1</Price></Book>
   <Book><Author>A2<Author><Name>B2</Name><Price>C2</Price></Book>
     ...
   <Book><Author>A(n-1)<Author><Name>B(n-1)</Name><Price>C(n-1)</Price></Book>
   <Book><Author>A(n)<Author><Name>B(n)</Name><Price>C(n)</Price></Book> 
</BookData>
```

I want it to end up like this.

```
 <BookData>
       <Book><Author>A1<Author><Name>B1</Name><Price>C1</Price></Book>
       <Book><Author>A2<Author><Name>B2</Name><Price>C2</Price></Book>
         ...
       <Book><Author>A(n-1)<Author><Name>B(n-1)</Name><Price>C(n-1)</Price></Book> 
    </BookData>
```

How can I do that with boost lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reverse-iterator `rbegin()`, but the conversion to its base iterator is always a bit tricky:

```
    auto& root = pt.get_child("BookData");
    root.erase(std::next(root.rbegin()).base());
```

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) has a neat illustration: [image]

See **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(
<BookData>
   <Book><Author>A1</Author><Name>B1</Name><Price>C1</Price></Book>
   <Book><Author>A2</Author><Name>B2</Name><Price>C2</Price></Book>
   <Book><Author>A(n-1)</Author><Name>B(n-1)</Name><Price>C(n-1)</Price></Book>
   <Book><Author>A(n)</Author><Name>B(n)</Name><Price>C(n)</Price></Book> 
</BookData>
)");

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    read_xml(iss, pt);

    auto& root = pt.get_child("BookData");
    root.erase(std::next(root.rbegin()).base());

    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
}
```

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BookData>

    <Book>
        <Author>A1</Author>
        <Name>B1</Name>
        <Price>C1</Price>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Author>A2</Author>
        <Name>B2</Name>
        <Price>C2</Price>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Author>A(n-1)</Author>
        <Name>B(n-1)</Name>
        <Price>C(n-1)</Price>
    </Book>
</BookData>
```

Comment: thank you very much. But I have a small question. If the `<BookData>` is a random name, How can I get the father node of `<Book>` node?

Comment: @ThếHảiNguyễn Huh. You just write the code to do it. Or, you could use an XML library, instead of a PropertyTree library.